# Who is depicted in the front cover of Beyonders: A World Without Heroes?

Tags: cover-art

I think I have read [*Beyonders: A World Without Heroes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beyonders:_A_World_Without_Heroes) a couple of times, at a high level of details, but I have troubles figuring out who is depicted in the [front cover of this book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZLg3.jpg):

[image]

Couldn't be *The Blind King* because... he is blind (and the depicted person is clearly not).

Couldn't be *Maldor* because he is much older according to book.

Then who?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Doctor Doom.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CoversAlwaysLie

Comment: Maybe contact the artist? https://antoniocaparo.com/

Comment: "*The building housed a great hall. Birds roosted in the rafters, and white streaks of droppings marked the floor and trestle tables. At the far end of the room, upon a moldering dais, a shabby man sat upon a battered throne. A dingy rag bound his eyes, a tarnished crown rested upon his gray hair, and a grimy green robe edged in dirty white fur enshrouded his body. He looked like some old homeless guy playing the part of a wise man in a soup-kitchen Christmas pageant.*" - The Blind King

Comment: *The bronze doors swung outward. A long blue carpet edged in silver led across the polished stone floor toward the dais, where the regent sat upon a great ivory chair. Crowds of elegantly arrayed courtiers clustered in groups off to either side. A portly old fellow with plump, healthy features, the regent looked much more like a real king than Galloran. A bejeweled circlet rested on his head. Rings glittered on his fingers. His fine raiment was a rich purple trimmed in gold.* - Dolan seems a better fit for the description

Comment: @trejder, haven't actually read the book but what makes you believe that the person on the cover is not blind? you can't even have a decent look at his eyes in the cover, how could you say he is blind

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for editing the question! If you think that Dolan is a best fit then why don't you make that an answer? To be honest, all your comments but together (that this is probably Dolan, because... cite... but it could also be The Blind King, because... cite... plus an info about cover artist) would in my opinion make simply the best answer to this question.

Comment: @trejder - Those aren't an answer. They're speculation and I don't do that in the answer box.

Comment: @shanu Valorum was so nice to turn my enormously huge image into smaller one (thanks, sorry, late night post!). If you take a look at [the original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZLg3.jpg) you can see all the details. Plus, from the storyline as The Blind King was nearly usually using an eye covers.

Comment: @Valorum What about answers like: "This isn't explained precisely nowhere, neither in universe (story) or out of universe (discussion with author), but this is most likely a Dolan because of the below part"? Do we accept answers here saying that there is no definitive answer at all and all we have all speculations?

Comment: @trejder - If you think that's an OK answer, then by all means post it. I have personal higher standards and don't usually post something unless I can back it up. In this case there's an artist and an author who are both alive and active on social media that can both be asked, so we don't need to guess.

Comment: @trejder, didn’t he wear the eye covers because of the displacer grafts? Or is that just what he says in the 2nd book? (it’s been a while since I’ve read the books)

Comment: @trejder yeah i read the character sketch of the blind king, he does wear eye covers. Anyway thanks for the clarification

Comment: @BlueSkinandGlowingRedEyes Unfortunately I read the book so long ago that I can't answer this question, sorry.

Answer (score 5):

The artist of that cover is [Antonio Caparo](https://antoniocaparo.com/antonio-javier-caparo-illustrations). In a [Blogspot post](https://antoniocaparo.blogspot.com/2011/02/beyonders.html) from 2011 he mentions the work he did on the cover.

[image: Image from Blogspot february 2011]

Apparently, the image was supposed to depict "the evil king", so that would be Maldor. And why he looks so youthful can be attributed to artistic license.